# MacBook A1398 has been turned off for years and will not turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, power

I’ve got a MacBook A1398 that has been laying around on a shelve for a minimum of 7 years which I’d like to try to revive. I’ve hooked up the MagSafe charger for around 12 hours and keeps showing the solid orange light. When trying the power button in multiple durations (single tap, 3 secs, 5 secs, 10 secs and 20 secs) nothing happens. No spinning fans, no lights, nothing.

I’m no electrical engineer, but I would be perfectly fine changing out the battery. Though, I’m not sure if it is the battery that needs replacement and ideally want to prevent spending unnecessary money.

Questions:

1. Is there any way for me to analyse what’s wrong with the machine?
2. If the battery is dead, wouldn’t the MacBook skip the battery and still boot if it’s connected to the wall?
3. Would it have any chance when hooking up the MacBook longer to the wall than I already did?

Edit: I just noticed that the MacBook’s fan is constantly revving up and down in intervals of 1 second or so. Probably not enough power to go through?

Comment: That model spans 2012 to 2015 MacBook Pro.  The battery is probably acting like a power sink. Detatch the battery and try powering up with only the MagSafe

Comment: @Allan thanks for your response. I’ve just edited my post, could you please check that out? I would think that what you’re saying would make perfect sense with that symptom?

Comment: At a minimum you should get constant fan spin.  Going up and down indicates a power issue.  [Reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).  If that doesn't work, disconnect the battery then try powering up.

Comment: When resetting the SMC and pressing the last of the four buttons (the power button) I immediately hear the revving of the fan stop, which is interesting. When releasing the buttons, the fan immediately starts with the revving again and booting still does not work. I’ll disconnect the battery sometime in the next days.

Comment: I just noticed that the MagSafe connector briefly changes color to green after the release and then turning orange again. I guess that’s confirmation the SMC is successfully reset. Again, I’ll be disconnecting the battery soon abd report back.

Comment: No need for all this back and forth. After this long with out charging, it is a battery in name only.